# typescript add properties to Vue library definitions

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I use vue which includes types. However I want to use some properties that are added by certain plugins.

e.g.

```
Vue.$ga
Vue.$router
```

Typescript complains that Vue does not have those properties. Can I somehow add those globally to the Vue definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface VueConstructor {
        $ga: any; // define real typings here if you want
        $router: any;
    }
}
```

You can find more info specific to Vue [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins)

Answer (score 5):

On main.ts, add:

```
Vue.prototype.$ga = 'your ga service'
```

Create a definition file 'my-file.d.ts' on your project /src folder.

```
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {

    interface Vue {
        $ga: any;
    }

    interface VueConstructor {
        $ga: any;
    }
}

declare module 'vue/types/options' {
    interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
        $ga?: any;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it inside your component by simple doing:

```
console.log(this.$ga); // your ga service
```