# use iView in Typescript and Vue.js project

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Based on the following introduction: 
 https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-vue-starter#single-file-components

I have get started to develop vue.js project based on Typescript. Follow up the introduction, it works ok.

But I have one question. Now I want to add `iView` UI framework to my project by add the following command to the entry file: `index.ts`:

```
import iView from 'iview';
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';

Vue.use(iView);
```

Then I get the error message:

[image]

it seems that both `import` command can't work. For the first one, now in the project, there is a file named `vue-shims.d.ts`, which contains the following lines:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

For the second error, no idea to fix it.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076772/typescript-add-properties-to-library-definitions

Comment: Read that file, but not fully understand yet. And not sure, if the question is duplicated.